# Matrix multiplication in Metal Shading Language

Tags: matrix, gpu, multiplication, metal, shading

I am working with Apple's Metal 2 framework. The official [Metal Shading Language Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), section 2.3. *Matrix Data Types* states that:

> Metal supports a subset of the matrix data types implemented by the system math library. The matrix type names supported are:
>   halfnxm and floatnxm. Where n and m are numbers of columns and rows. n and m must be 2, 3, or 4.

So just to be sure: The largest matrix that I can define in a shader function is a 4x4 matrix?

What about larger matrices? Do I have to implement them by myself?

Answer (score 1):

Those small matrices are primarily for doing 2D and 3D graphics work.

If you want to multiply larger matrices, look at the `MPSMatrix` class and the *Matrices and Vectors* section of the Metal Performance Shaders framework.

If you want to do a matrix multiplication as part of some larger compute kernel then you'll have to implement it yourself. (There is some Metal sample code for this.)

Comment: Thanks! The matrix multiplication would indeed be part of some larger compute kernel. Could you point me to the mentioned sample code?

Comment: [Here's one sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MPSMatrixMultiplicationSample/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: It looks like the sample code I had in mind is now replaced by the MPS example that @warrenm linked to. Which is unfortunate, although it was probably out of date.